# Sequentially update rows by group using data.table

Tags: r, loops, data.table

I am fairly new to R. I have a hypothetical dataset containing prescriptions from various different patients and drug types. What I would like to do is to create episodes of drug use, i.e., I would like to see for how long a patient used the drug. The loop mentioned in post [sequentially update rows in data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41363526/sequentially-update-rows-in-data-table) works for me, but I am not sure how I can make sure that the loop starts over when encountering a new patient identifier or drug type.

These are some rows from the dataset "AllDrugs":

```
DrugType    ID  Duration StartPrescr    EndPrescr   n
1           1   90       5-3-2020       3-6-2020    1
1           2   30       7-1-2020       6-2-2020    1
1           2   30       14-1-2020      12-6-2020   2
1           2   30       21-01-2020     19-6-2020   3
```

Note: n is a number indicating the prescription by ID and DrugType

This is the current loop:

```
 for (i in 2:nrow(AllDrugs)) {
   if (AllDrugs[i,StartPrescr] >= AllDrugs[i-1,EndPrescr]) {
     AllDrugs[i, EndPrescr:= StartPrescr+ Duration]
   } else {
     AllDrugs[i, EndPrescr:= AllDrugs[i-1,EndPrescr] + Duration]
   }
 }
```

This is what I get:

```
DrugType    ID  Duration    StartPrescr EndPrescr   n
1           1   90          5-3-2020    3-6-2020    1
1           2   30          7-1-2020    3-7-2020    1
1           2   30          14-1-2020   2-8-2020    2
1           2   30          21-01-2020  1-9-2020    3
```

This is what I want:

```
DrugType    ID  Duration    StartPrescr EndPrescr   n
1           1   90          5-3-2020    3-6-2020    1
1           2   30          7-1-2020    6-2-2020    1
1           2   30          14-1-2020   7-3-2020    2
1           2   30          21-01-2020  6-4-2020    3
```

How can I shift the prescriptions based on the duration of the prescription by ID and DrugType? Note: this is an example of one drug type, but DrugType could also be 2, or 3 etc.

Comment: What is the idea behind `StartEpisode` and why did `StartPrescr` change in your desired output?

Comment: The idea behind StartEpisode is that I would like to go to one row per continuous use of DrugType after a few more modifications. I have deleted this variable in the dataset for now to make my question clearer.  StartPrescr should be the same in the input and desired output (I have updated the example rows).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work for you?

```r
shift_end <- function(en,dur) {
  if(length(en)>1) for(i in 2:length(en)) en[i] = en[i-1] + dur[i]
  return(en)
}

df[order(ID, DrugType,StartPrescr), EndPrescr:=shift_end(EndPrescr,Duration), by=.(ID,DrugType)]
```

Result:

```r
   DrugType ID Duration StartPrescr  EndPrescr n
1:        1  1       90  2020-03-05 2020-06-03 1
2:        1  2       30  2020-01-07 2020-02-06 1
3:        1  2       30  2020-01-14 2020-03-07 2
4:        1  2       30  2020-01-21 2020-04-06 3
```

Data Source:

```
df <- structure(list(
  DrugType = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
  ID = c(1, 2, 2, 2),
  Duration = c(90, 30, 30, 30),
  StartPrescr = structure(c(18326,18268, 18275, 18282), class = "Date"),
  EndPrescr = structure(c(18416, 18298, 18425, 18432), class = "Date"),
  n = c(1, 1, 2, 3)), row.names = c(NA,-4L),
  class = c("data.table", "data.frame")
)
```

Comment: I ran the code over the whole dataset and it worked perfectly for every ID and DrugType!